# Use a uniqueidentifier column for hash partitioning

Tags: sql-server, azure, modeling, azure-synapse, uniqueidentifier

I have 2 fact tables: fact patient and fact production

Both use several columns with uniqueidentifier, I would like to know if it is a good practice and recommended to use this type of column as hash distribution for the tables (currently they are round-robin).

Expect know what column to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You should choose distribution column(s) in such a way that column(s) have many unique values and data are distributed evenly in all distributions.
- You can use the below query to check the number of rows that are stored in each distribution for the chosen distribution column. Make sure the data is evenly distributed.

```sql
-- Find data skew for a distributed table
DBCC PDW_SHOWSPACEUSED('dbo.FactPatient');
```

- It is recommended to have zero nulls or few null values in the distribution column. Also, that column should not be a date column.
- The distribution column should be the column that is used mostly for *joins*, aggregation like *group by*, *having*. Columns which are used in  *where* should not be chosen as the distribution column. It is also recommended to choose a distribution column that minimizes **data movement.**
- It is not always possible to have both evenly distributed data and minimized data movement. Thus, find the right balance between minimizing data skew and data movement in choosing the distribution column.

**Reference:**
[Distributed tables design guidance - Azure Synapse Analytics | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-distribute)